# collection.map is not a function at Promise.all.then

Tags: javascript

Alright, guys

I'm new to `promises` and am trying to map the result of loading in CSVs via `promises`, to then perform subsequent applications on it. Is Async mapping allowed? Is there an alternative approach to map after using `promises`? Or am I being stupid and missing something completely simple?

```
var csv = (url) => new Promise(function(resolve) {
    d3.csv(url, function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) { 
            d.String = d.String;
            d.Integer = +d.Integer;
        })
    resolve(data);
    });
});

Promise.all([ 
    csv('content.csv'),
    csv('moreContent.csv')
])
.then(([csvOne, csvTwo]) => { 
    var collection = { csvOne, csvTwo };

    var aveageMap = {};

    collection.map((d,i) => {
        if (!aveageMap[d.String]) {
            aveageMap[d.String] = {
                sum: 0,
                average: 0
            };
        }
        var theWord = aveMap[d.String];
        theWord.sum += +d.Integer;
        theWord.average = theWord.sum / collection.length;
    });

    console.log(aveageMap);

});
```

***For the comments and answers below***

Using an array **is** an object, but returns a complete merger of the two CSVs... Which affects the `theWord.sum / collection.length` line... Whilst it works to some degree, I wanted to use an array of objects so that I could get an output like the one below, and access each object independently if needed.

```
collection {
    dataCSV {
        String: , Integer: ,
        String: , Integer: ,
    },
    dataCSV2 {
        String: , Integer: ,
        String: , Integer: ,
    }
}
```

Comment: I see two potential issues here. 1) collection is an object, which doesn't have a `.map()` method. 2) You should be calling `resolve` in your callback for `d3.csv`. Right now it resolves before the data is ready.

Comment: indeed this has nothing to do with Promises per se

Comment: collection {   } should this be an `object` or an `array` collection [ ] . Your json and the terms used is quite confusing.

Comment: Sorry about the way the question is written, it should be an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- It looks like you are trying to combine the two arrays returned by `csv`, which you can do via `csvOne.concat(csvTwo)`, or `[...csvOne, ...csvTwo]` (using es6).
- Since you're not actually returning everything in your mapping function, it would be more appropriate to use `.forEach`.
- To me, it also looks like `d.word` should be `d.String` (unless they are the same). Also note that many consider it bad style to have capitalized property names (especially those with already existing class names, like `String`), so you may want to rename `d.String` and `d.Integer` to `d.string` and `d.integer` or something more descriptive. It also likes like `ageMap`should be `aveageMap`.

All together, it looks like:

```
var csv = (url) => new Promise(function(resolve) {
    d3.csv(url, function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) { 
            d.string = d['String'];
            d.integer = +d['Integer'];
        })
        resolve(data);
    });
});
Promise.all([ 
    csv('content.csv'),
    csv('moreContent.csv')
])
.then(([csvOne, csvTwo]) => { 
    var aveageMap = {};
    var collection = [...csvOne, ...csvTwo];
    collection.forEach((d,i) => {
        if (!aveageMap[d.string]) {
            aveageMap[d.string] = {
                sum: 0,
                average: 0
            };
        }
        var theWord = aveageMap[d.string];
        theWord.sum += +d.integer;
        theWord.average = theWord.sum / collection.length;
    });    
    console.log(aveageMap);

});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I have a query, which I've appended to the question

Comment: I've played around with it, it works - the only thing is the `collection.length`... As it returns the length of the array, not the length of objects that make up the array if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call map on a non-array-object, if you want to be able to call `map` make it an `array` instead of an `object`.

```
var collection = [ csvOne, csvTwo ];
```

Comment: An array **is** an object in Javascript.

Comment: @connexo yes, but `map` is a method on arrays. `obj = {name: "bob"}` followed by `obj.map(x => x)` will give you an error. Now try it with `[ "bob" ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how i understand your question.

```
Promise.all([csv('content.csv'),csv('moreContent.csv')]).then(([...csvs])=>{
  const collection = {};
  csvs.forEach(csv=>{
    if(!collection[csv.String]) 
      collection[csv.String] = {sum:0, average:0}
      .....
  })
});
```